# L78S05C only supplying 4.88 volts?

Tags: power-supply, linear-regulator

I'm working on a linear 5 V power supply for the first time. I'm using the [L78S05C](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78s.pdf) as I was hoping for a little elbow room on the amperage over the standard 1.5 A version.

Circuit tested perfectly on the bread board, so had at it. Completely done, it would not power up my device (needing 5 V). I tore it down to find the transformer (Hammond 166N6) 6.3+0+6.3, while reading over 12 V using a multimeter, is really NOT the RMS voltage. I don't remember exactly, but barely getting 8.5 V RMS using my oscilloscope.

I'm guessing the lower voltage, voltage drop from the full-wave rectifier and then again the 2 V drop from the L78S05 was my issue.

Moving on, to be sure I send 15 V to the L78S05 using my adjustable DC voltage regulator and the output of L78 is only 4.8 volts.

I added two 100 uF capacitors, one on Vi and one on Vo to ground, besides the recommended 0.33 uF and 0.1 uF (see Figure 17 from the datasheet below).

[image: Figure 17 from L78S datasheet]

I figured instead of aimlessly de-soldering the additional caps, trial and error, I should ask here why the voltage is so low.

Comment: What is your current draw?

Comment: The 166N6 has a 6.3 volt centre-tapped secondary - that is, the full secondary voltage is 6.3 volts.  The 8.5 V you mention is higer than I would expect (but possilbe) for the no-load voltage.  The transformer is rated for 25.2 VA, which corresponds nicely to 6.3 V at 4 Amp.

Comment: The 200uF filtering is sufficient for 100mA load maximum otherwise the voltage falls.

Comment: If you have no load at all the output voltage may be out of regulation. Even if you have load, it still would not output exactly 5.0000 volts, 4.88V is within specs.

Comment: Im not sure, about the current draw, but to have a LED in circuit with a 330 Ohm resistor. The 6.3 + 6.3 to each other producing 12.6V is peak to peak 12.6. The RMS is 8V. I assumed that the output was RMS rated... Now I know 
Michal, Understood. Care to explain how you determined that (Or point me in the right direction ?)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the data sheet, the nominal output voltage is given as 4.8 to 5.2 volts.  Therefore an output of 4.88 volts is within the specification.

Comment: I did notice that, and thought since it was advertised as a 5V that through circuit design you could adjust a little here or there. It seams strange that I would have to hunt through the lot to find one putting out 5V.. Am I missing something? Is there a better component that puts out 5v every day, all day long ?

Comment: @Hoops There is **no component** that puts out exactly 5.000V every day, all day long. In the real world everything has a tolerance. You can find regulators that are more accurate than the 7805 but you must live with some non-zero error.

Comment: Elliot, I see now there are variable voltage regs based off this (and other regulators) Im guessing that I should design around one of those and once I find what delivers the goods, pin the dial or swap out with a fixed cap or resistor for that value...

Answer (score 0):

a small short of maybe some tin splatter on your PCB hold it up to some strong light and look the board over (can be a tiny droplet or a tiny copper slither from board making ) . does the 7805 warm up quickly ?

Comment: How would a short cause this?

Comment: 2winners, wasnt ignoring you. Have been having time constraints, but plenty of splatter everywhere except the board. And not enough heat to know if it even has any real current through it. I do have a big heat sink, with the thinnest coat of thermal compound I could smoothly get on... Thank you for responding..

Comment: @pipe some times when making new boards some thin slithers of copper do not eat away by the acid correctly and work like a resistor and the 78XX voltage drops when exeeding rated current but don't blow up if its just over the limit but not a full short ..i mention the board short as you said it worked well on the breadboard

Answer (score 0):

[image: bridge rectifier output waveforms with and without capacitor filter]

<sub>Original image source: [Industrial-Electronics.com, Capacitor Filter, Fig.28](http://www.industrial-electronics.com/epst-3e_7b.html)</sub>

The capacitor filter must cover all load demand when rectified voltage is currently lower than capacitor voltage in respect of desired output ripple, another words the rectifier feeds capacitor/load in t1 time only. In t2 only capacitor supplies the load. In your case the lowest point of capacitor voltage should not be less than 8V (5V+2V_drop+1V_reserve).

The output ripple depends on capacitor size and load in way the higher load the large cap you need. If you have a scope than just measure the ripple at full load and add capacity until you reach desired result (or better start from bigger capacity and lower it until ripple is still sufficient).

Your issue with 4.88V can also be caused by too low load. These regulators does not work proper at light loads so maybe add 1k resistor parallel to regulator output should be a solution. But if you have Led connected as you mention this should not be this case.

The output voltage drop to 4.88V can be caused overloading L78S05C also.

Comment: I will check current draw as someone else asked figuring I should know that, and than try adding additional resistors to increase the load. Im not sure of the listed amperage requirements of my device, but should be able to tally that up reasonably quickly. I will try to duplicate that load and measure, adding a few more resistors.